# Problemas para obtener dato de una tabla HTML con función click JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo una tabla `html` la cual crea las filas dinamicamente a partir de una consulta `MySQL`.

**Código HTML de la TABLA**

```
<table id=tablaEmpleadosAdmin class="table table-hover table-responsive-xl">
                                <thead class="thead-dark text-center">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Id_Empleado</th>
                                      <thscope="col">Nombre</th>Paterno</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody id="bodyTable-NE" class="text-center">
                                </tbody>
</table>
```

**Resultado del Relleno de la tabla**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Código JS**

```
 $('#tablaEmpleadosAdmin tr').click(function() {
 var dato = $(this).find('td').eq(1);
 alert(dato);
 });
```

**Código php de la consulta MySQL**

```
  public function todosEmpleados() {
    try {

        //De la clase heredada "Conexion" se obtiene la funcion Conectar_BD
        $this->Conectar_BD();
        //Se asigna la cadena de texto de la consulta de MySQL
        $this->query = 'SELECT empleados.id_empleado,empleados.nombre_empleado FROM empleados INNER JOIN puestos on puestos.id_puesto=empleados.id_puesto INNER JOIN dependencia ON dependencia.id_dependencia = empleados.id_dependencia WHERE empleados.id_estado=1 ORDER BY id_dependencia,nombre_empleado DESC';
        //Preparamos la sentencia a executar
        $this->consulta = $this->conexion_bd->prepare($this->query);
        //Ejecucion de la sentencia
        $this->consulta->execute();
        //Se almacena el resultado
        $this->consulta->store_result();
        //Vincular nombres a la sentencia preparada
        $this->consulta->bind_result($id_empleado, $nombre_empleado, $apellido_paterno, $apellido_materno, $direccion, $telefono, $id_dependencia,$nombre_dep, $id_puesto,$puesto);
        //Se obtienen las filas de la consulta
        $num_rows = $this->consulta->num_rows;
        //Variable que construira la tabla
        $tblHtml = '';
        //contador de items
        $items = 1;
        //Se compara si existe al menos un resultado de la consulta
        if ($num_rows >= 1) {
            //Se obtienen los resultados de la consulta
            while ($this->consulta->fetch()) {

                    $tblHtml .= '<tr class=fila_empadmin>
                        <td>' . $items . '</td>
                                    <td>' . $id_empleado . '</td>
                                    <td>' . $nombre_empleado . '</td>
                                </tr>';

                $items++;
            }
            echo $tblHtml;
        } else {
            echo "No hay registros";
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {

    }
}
```

**Código Ajax donde se envía la consulta**

```
function todosEmpleados() {
$.ajax({
    url: '../../php/instancias.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {Funcion: 'Empleados-todos'}
})
        .done(function (data) {
            $('#bodyTable-NE').empty();
            $('#bodyTable-NE').append(data);
        })
        .fail(function () {
            console.log("error");
        });
}
```

El problema es que al darle click no se ejecuta la función para obtener el dato del empleado.

Comment: ¿Cómo hace el llenado de su tabla ? ¿Solo las filas las crea dinámica mente o la tabla completa?

Comment: @Dev.Joel Ediatre la pregunta para anexar el código

Comment: Listo @Dev.Joel ya agregue lo que faltaba del código.

Comment: exactamente que quieres obtener con `.eq(1)` ? solo el id del empleado?

Comment: @iuninefrendor Si, ya que despues con eso tengo que llenar un formulario para editarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que sucede al ser un llenado dinámico, necesita utilizar [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) para asignar un `listener`  correctamente para un elemento existente en el `DOM` , para su caso puede utilizar la `tabla` *tablaEmpleadosAdmin* o directamente `document`

Además si desea obtener el texto recuerde utilizar `text()`.

```
$('#tablaEmpleadosAdmin').on('click','tr',function(){
  var dato = $(this).find('td').eq(1).text();//Primera columna
  alert(dato);
});
```

o

```
$(document).on('click','#tablaEmpleadosAdmin tr',function(){
    var dato = $(this).find('td').eq(1).text();//Primera columna
    alert(dato);
});
```

Comment: Ya edite mi código y con esos cambios ha funcionado perfectamente.

Comment: Perfecto @FernyCortez , Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Agrega un `.text()` despues del `.eq(1)` para obtener el texto del 2° `<td>`, si el `.click()` no funciona, puedes usar la función `.on('click',function()...`

```js
$('#tablaEmpleadosAdmin tr').on('click',function() {
    var dato = $(this).find('td').eq(1).text();
    alert(dato);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<table id=tablaEmpleadosAdmin class="table table-hover table-responsive-xl">
    <thead class="thead-dark text-center">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Id_Empleado</th>
            <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="bodyTable-NE" class="text-center">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0001</td>
      <td>Martha</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: He hecho lo del codigo tal cual como en la respuesta. pero no funciona. En lo personal pienso que tiene que ver con que las filas se llenan desde el `php` porque no ejecuta la funcion.